# Blank listview getting in android

Tags: android

```
public class Setting extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ListView listView1;
    ImageView backbutton;
    String Url = "http://182.71.212.110:8083/api/values/userdetails";
    String Id;
    String Designation;
    String EmployeeName;
    JSONArray _jarray;

    DataModel datamodel = new DataModel();
    ArrayList<DataModel> list = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        backbutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
        backbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

        new GetUserdetail().execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.backbutton) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    class GetUserdetail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                String json = HttpHitter.ExecuteData(Url);
                _jarray = new JSONArray(json);
                System.out.println("_jarray" + _jarray);

                for (int i = 0; i <= _jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject _obj = _jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    if (Id != null) {
                        datamodel.setId(_obj.getString("Id"));
                    }
                    if (Designation != null) {
                        datamodel.setDesignation(_obj.getString("Designation"));
                    }
                    if (EmployeeName != null) {
                        datamodel.setEmployeeName(_obj
                                .getString("EmployeeName"));
                    }

                    list.add(datamodel);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            CustomList adapter = new CustomList(Setting.this, list);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }

}



public class DataModel implements Parcelable {
    private String Id = "";

    private String Designation = "";

    private String EmployeeName = "";

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return Designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.Designation = designation;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return EmployeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.EmployeeName = employeeName;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public DataModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DataModel(Parcel in) {
        Id = in.readString();
        EmployeeName = in.readString();
        Designation = in.readString();

    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeString(Id);
        dest.writeString(EmployeeName);
        dest.writeString(Designation);
    }

}


public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    private ArrayList<DataModel> arrModel;

    public CustomList(Context context, ArrayList<DataModel> arrModel) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrModel = arrModel;
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtDesc;

        ImageView locationimage;
        ImageView roleimageview;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.settingrowitem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowcontact_txtName);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowcontact_txtrole);

            holder.locationimage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.roleimageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtDesc.setText(arrModel.get(position).getEmployeeName());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(arrModel.get(position).getDesignation());

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }

        else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f5f6f1"));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrModel.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrModel.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

}
```

There are three class which I have use to parse data from from web service and and trying to print in Listview .I am able to do Json parsing and getting data from server `insetting.javaclass`:

```
list.add(datamodel);
```

and bind this in list in onpostexcute method:

```
CustomList adapter = new CustomList(Setting.this, list);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Using this i am trying to print data in listview item but I am getting blank value in each item while Number Json is 49 and i am getting that 49 but getDesignation and getEmploye  I am getting blank value please check and tell me where I am doing mistake I have tried much unable to get Print that value please check suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you inistailizind the **Id,Designation and EmployeeName**, it will be null itself. so doInBackground wont add any datamodel. remove the check

```
class GetUserdetail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String json = HttpHitter.ExecuteData(Url);
            _jarray = new JSONArray(json);
            System.out.println("_jarray" + _jarray);

            for (int i = 0; i <= _jarray.length(); i++) {
                DataModel datamodel = new DataModel();
                JSONObject _obj = _jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                datamodel.setId(_obj.getString("Id"));
                datamodel.setDesignation(_obj.getString("Designation"));
                datamodel.setEmployeeName(_obj.getString("EmployeeName"));
                list.add(datamodel);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(Setting.this, list);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the model inside the for loop and try once.

Comment: still am getting blank value

Comment: i dont why this issue is coming

Answer (score 0):

To identify changes in your list item you should call 
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
call it before setting adapter to list view.